# Iterate through filelist from two directions

Tags: linux, bash, loops, rsync

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash 


for i in `ls /file-directory/ | grep -v static-backup | grep -v fileGroup1 | grep -v fileGroup2`
 do
 echo $i
 rsync --delete -avz --size-only --exclude "$i/stuff1" --exclude "$i/stuff2" --exclude "$i/stuff3" --exclude "$i/stuff4" --exclude "$i/stuff5" --exclude "$i/stuff6" /file-directory/$i otherServer:/file-directory/ && echo " exit code: " $?" $i" || echo " exit code: " $?" $i"
 done
```

The script iterates through a file directory and rsyncs its subdirectories, excluding certain fileGroups and portions of those filegroup's directories. I would like this script to spawn two rsync jobs, one that starts at the top of the directory and another that starts at the bottom. They would iterate in opposite directions and meet in the middle.

This is relatively simple to do with normal counting for loops, and wouldn't bee to hard in something like python (you could just save the number of directories as a variable, then iterate using that var). How can I do something similar in bash?

Comment: Bash has a built-in "counting for loop".  See [The C-style for-loop (Bash Hackers Wiki)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for).

Comment: `grep -v -e a -e b -e c` has the same result as `grep -v a | grep -v b | grep -v c` but it's about three times faster because it only scans the input once and it doesn't need to spawn three children.

Comment: Also, I presume your intention is to run the two rsync processes in parallel. You should take a look at [Gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) rather than trying to roll-your-own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `&` in `bash` to `fork` a process. or even loop.
I am sure there are more than one way to achieve this, but here's one way.

**Pseudo code.**

Get listing of files in two separate arrays such that they each contain half of listing (for even).
For odd files , second array will contain one more file.
Loop through first array and fork a process using `&`
Loop through second array and fork second process using `&`

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_len=$(ls /file-directory/ |wc -l|awk '{print $NF}')
midpoint=$(($dir_len / 2))

array1=()
array2=()
count=0

#Loop through files and divide contents into two arrays  
for i in $(ls /file-directory/)
do
  count=$(($count + 1))
  if [ $count -le $midpoint ] ; then
    array1+=($i)
  elif [[ $count -gt $midpoint && $count -le $dir_len ]] ; then
    array2+=($i)
  fi
done

#Loop through first array and fork     
for i in "${array1[@]}"
do
  echo $i
  #your rsync command here
done&

#Loop through second array and fork
for j in "${array2[@]}"
do
  echo $j
  #your rsync command here
done &
```

Note:
`&` is optional in second for loop as u can run it in foreground since there are only two processes.
Also, you may want harden the script for undesired files or if folder is empty.

Edit.

Based upon type of files u need to rsync, refer to this link for inspiration instead of using ‘ls /folder_name/‘.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names

Comment: `for i in $(ls /file-directory/)` breaks if any filename contains a char in IFS or a newline.

Comment: I agree , this is not a comprehensive solution but a way to get started. OP can refer to  this link on how to deal with special files. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names

Comment: parsing output of `ls` is a bad idea in most cases. shell globs can normally provide the same functionality more safely and reliably, e.g. `for i in /file-directory/*`